# Synchronizing Thunderbird15.0.1-Contacts with cardDAV-Server without using SOGO-Connector

Tags: ubuntu, sync, thunderbird, contacts

I have my own server (running ubuntu 12.04) on which I installed ownCloud and were able to successfully synchronize my  Calendar via CalDAV. But when trying to synchronize my contacts with CardDAV, nothing worked. Everywhere I searched, all I could find was using SOGO-Connector which didn't work at all.

By the way: One thing SOGO-Connector did, was asking me twice for my master password every time I started Thunderbird.

Is this an ownCloud-specific (v. 4.04) problem?

If anyone has a solution wihout ownCloud or without cardDAV in general, this is fine, but it shouldn't store my contact data anywhere else than on my server (that means no cloud storage solution).

It may help to know, that I have a working SparkleShare synchronisation.

EDIT: Now using Radicale instead of ownCloud but with the same problems.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble; there just doesn't seem to be a good way to sync contacts in Thunderbird, whether via CardDAV or otherwise -- even its LDAP interface appears to be read-only, which is less than useful for my purposes. I'm also actively looking for a solution, and you'll be the first to know if I find one.

Comment: @Aaron Miller Found a Solution (kind of a workaround but works very well)

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up -- that gives me an option I didn't have before.

Comment: Late update: If you're willing to downgrade to Thunderbird 10 or upgrade to Thunderbird 17 (both of which have an extended-support release available), you can use the free SoGo Connector, which does quite a good job of two-way CardDAV synchronization. It works quite well for me, at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my own problem:

1. Installing Evolution and adding the CardDAV-adressbook
2. Installing EDS Contact Integration into Thunderbird

That's it, wasn't that hard.

Only problem: You have to specify an email account at least once to setup evolution (can be removed later).

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround in my special case:

The personal adressbook integrated in thunderbird is located in a file called abook.mab. Synchronizing this file with the help of a symlink and SparkleShare synchronizes my adressbook without using CardDAV.